# How to use the Akka ask pattern without blocking

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, future

Hi I have a actor which is responsible for fetching data from a database, turning it into a list and sending it back to the sender. I am using the `ask` pattern to receive response from my actor, because I don't want to use `await.result` because this approach will block the thread which is not good.

I wrote the following code to get the response from my actor (I just skipped the db code to keep it simple but logic remains same) :

```
class MyActor extends Actor{
   var list = new MutableList[Int]()
   list+=1
   list+=2
   list+=3
   list+=4

   def receive ={
     case "returnAlist"=>
       println("sending back list "+list +"of size "+list.size)
       sender ! list
     case message => 
       unhandled(message)
   }
}

object Test extends App{
  val system = ActorSystem("testing")
  val MyActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "InstitutionUserSuggestion")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(15 seconds)
  var ResultList = new MutableList[Int]()
  val future:Future[MutableList[Int]] = ask(MyActor,"returnAlist").mapTo[MutableList[Int]] 
  future.onComplete { 
    case Success(result)=>
      println(" in sucees start")
      println("value of result "+ result.size)
      println("ResultList=result")
      ResultList = result
      println("value of ResultList "+ ResultList.size)
      println("in Success end")
    case Failure(e)=>
      println(" in failure")
      e.printStackTrace()
  }

  println("returned list size is " + ResultList.size + " and its contents" + ResultList)


}
```

Here is the output of the code above:

```
sending back list MutableList(1, 2, 3, 4)of size 4
returned list size is 0 and its contenstsMutableList()
in sucees start
value of result 4
 ResultList=result
value of ResultList 4
 in Success end
```

My problem is that the `onComplete` code is executed at the end I need to display contents of my list `ResultList` on the console but this line

```
println("returned list size is "+ResultList.size +" and its contensts" +ResultList)
```

which I write after the `onComplete` block I think it is executing before the `onComplete` block, so at the end nothing is in the list `ResultList`, so I am unable to print its items to the console.

Please help me, what should I do to receive a list of items from the actor without blocking and after that display it on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to block, by waiting on the response of the actor, so you are using `Future` correctly. The code in the `onComplete` function is executed, when your actor responds with the list.

And since you don't want to block and handle it asynchronously, your last `println` statement is executed while your actor has not yet responded.

You can print the content of the list in the `onComplete` block:

```
object Test extends App{
  val system = ActorSystem("testing")
  val MyActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "InstitutionUserSuggestion")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(15 seconds)

  val future: Future[List[Int]] = ask(MyActor,"returnAlist").mapTo[List[Int]] 
  future.onComplete { 
    case Success(result)=>
      println("returned list size is " + result.size +" and its contents" + result)
    case Failure(e)=>
      println("in failure")
      e.printStackTrace()
  }
}
```

As a side note, I used an immutable `List` which is more idiomatic Scala than using mutable collections, like `MutableList`.

Comment: but what should i do if i want to print the contents of the list after onComplete block

Comment: That is not possible without using `Await.result`. You either write it in the `Future.onComplete` block or use `Await.result` to block and wait on the result and print it afterwards.

Comment: ok thanks one last thing i want to ask ..i am using ask pattern with onComplete but still i have to provide a timeout why is that so ?

Comment: Because don't want to wait forever on the response of the actor. If the actor does not repond (within the implicit `timeout`) the `Future` will turn into a `Failure`. More info in the [akka docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future)

Comment: so my code is not blocking even there is a timeout of 15 second right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81290/discussion-between-peter-neyens-and-user3801239).